# How should I effectively display result of a SQL query?

Tags: website-design, html

so I am making a website and I have a mysql database that stores all the information of users.

This is the structure of my database

```
CREATE TABLE `profile` (
`userID` INT(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`username` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL ,
`position` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL ,
`champion` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL ,
`level` INT(2) NOT NULL,
`division` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL ,
`name` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
`lolking` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE (`username`)
);
```

In my website I want to implement a function that people can search other users based on "division" and "posistion". So I use

```
SELECT * FROM profiles where `division` ="sth" and `position` = "sth"
```

I am currently displaying the result in a table since the database is relatively small. However, as the database has more queries, what would be an effective way to show users the result? I am thinking maybe I should build a table with tabs that each tabs show certain number of rows but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just modify your table in order to provide the following:

- paging
- sorting
- filtering/search
- number of items to display

[image]

[image source](http://beckelman.net/2008/10/23/client-side-table-sorting-paging-and-filtering-with-jquery-demo/)

As an addition you can introduce tree-table and use some attribute(s) as a part of the tree structure, but I really doubt you need that. So the suggestion is to enhance your current table.